# How to form http POST request to handle xml data file

Tags: spring, rest, https, postman

My requirement is to accept xml data file that may be gziped in HTTPS POST request and request may be chunked.
Request body WILL have the type of application/.xml.

I am using Postman to make request and java spring to write the controller and rest of the api code.
My questions is how will my request will look like, either it will be form data with xml file in input or raw body with xml selected in postman.

I am finding it hard to make a curl for it.

Here is the example request requirement:
[image]